# Good way to combine React and Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, reactjs

I am working on a project to combine React and Leaflet, but I must say I am having some hard time with the semantics.

As most of the stuff is managed by Leaflet directly, I don't know if it would make sense to add the Leaflet map instance as state in the React Component or not.

Same problem when it comes to creating markers with Leaflet, as it does not return anything, I don't have anything to render really. The logic itself seems blurry to me.

Here is what I started to make. It's working but I feel like I'm writing bad code and missing the concept.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

/* DOING ALL THE REQUIRE */
var Utils = require('../core/utils.js');

var Livemap = React.createClass({
    uid: function() {
        var uid = 0;
        return function(){
            return uid++;
        };
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            uid: this.uid()
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var map = L.map('map-' + this.state.uid, {
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 20,
            layers: [L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'})],
            attributionControl: false,
        });
        map.fitWorld();
        return this.setState({
            map: map
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='map' id={'map-'+this.state.uid}></div>
        );
    }
});

(function(){
    Utils.documentReady(function(){
        React.render(
            <Livemap />,
            document.body
        )
    });
})();
```

So my questions are:

- Does this sample seem legit?
- How would you approach the logic of adding markers and managing their events?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- You don't need to manage uniqueness, i.e. "UID", yourself. Instead, you can use [`getDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode) to access the component's real node. Leaflet's API supports either a string selector or an HTMLElement instance.
- Leaflet is managing rendering, so the `map` should not live on `state`. Only store data in `state` that affects React's rendering of the DOM element.

Beyond those two points, use the Leaflet API normally and tie callbacks from your React component to the Leaflet map as you like. React is simply a wrapper at this point.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Livemap extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        var map = this.map = L.map(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this), {
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 20,
            layers: [
                L.tileLayer(
                    'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                    {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'})
            ],
            attributionControl: false,
        });

        map.on('click', this.onMapClick);
        map.fitWorld();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.map.off('click', this.onMapClick);
        this.map = null;
    }

    onMapClick = () => {
        // Do some wonderful map things...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='map'></div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello I am wondering if you could take the time to explain me some stuff relating to the use of Leaflet and React.
I want to add some very customized marker (so I will use iconDiv with some html in it) and want to add different event on those elements (the marker itself and some specific part of the marker) how would you do it ? Since ReactComponent don't really return html.

Comment: @SwannPolydor, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you open a new question and post some code?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this solution builds a new map on every `Livemap render`, doesn't it? Shouldn't we avoid this situation?

Comment: Because `render` returns the same thing every time, React will never touch the real DOM after the first render. This won't build a new map on every re-render. To improve this even more, you can tell React never to update as suggested in [using React with other libraries](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/use-react-with-other-libraries.html) by returning `false` from `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Note the 
  this.getDOMNode()
has been deprecated in React. You now use
  React.findDOMNode(this)

Comment: Thanks, @PhoeniceusAgelaius. I updated the code to use the latest API.

Comment: @RossAllen Don't you need to use bind when registering handler for the map click? e.g. this.onMapClick.bind(this)?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava `React.createClass` ["autobound"](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html) functions declared on Objects passed to it. If you use `createClass` you do not need a separate `bind` call. If you are using ES6 classes, you are definitely right; you need to bind.

Comment: @RossAllen Thanks this is good to know. Will check into it further.

Answer (score 22):

As an additional, less-detailed answer, PaulLeCam's react-leaflet component seems popular. Haven't used it yet but it looks promising:

https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet

**UPDATE:** It's solid. Haven't used many of the features yet but the codebase is well-written and easy to follow and extend, and what I've used works great out of the box.

Comment: How do you use the base components he provides?  Are these supposed to be used as separate React components outside of the <Map /> component?

Comment: @maxwell depends on your needs -- I generally render them within `<Map>` at some point down the component tree.