# Tiles not ordered correctly when using LeafletJS with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, leaflet

I am using the `LeafletJS` plugin to display a full page map in a `ReactJS` single page app. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26762020/341008). However, the tiles are not displayed in correct order. They are ordered randomly (?). I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34559785/341008) but in that case the order was fixed on page refresh. That is not true for me. My code is (excluding boilerplate):

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/atlas.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      Loading...
    </div>
    <script src="javascripts/atlas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**App.jsx**

```
import LiveMap from './LiveMap';
// App component
const App = () => (
    <LiveMap />
)
export default App;
```

**LiveMap.jsx**

```
class LiveMap extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id='map'></div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let _map = this.map = L.map(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
        L.tileLayer(
            'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(_map);    
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {...}

    shouldComponentUpdate() {return false;}
};
export default LiveMap;
```

Comment: Try setting a timeout before you render the map. `componentDidMount` can be somewhat misleading in that the element has been inserted into the DOM but not fully rendered (no width and height). Leaflet needs the width and height to render properly...

Comment: What are your `atlas.css` and `atlas.js` files made of? The shuffled tiles is usually a symptom of not loading `leaflet.css` stylesheet.

Comment: @SkipJack tried that. Didn't help.

Comment: @ghybs I tried loading `leaflet.css` explicitly. Still no success.

Comment: @341008 if it's not either of those things then I'm kind of at a loss.. Can you add a live example of the issue?

Comment: @341008 were you able to resolve this? I'm interested as to what it ended up being...

Comment: Have you found a solution @341008? I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your issue is that the element has not fully rendered by the time your code executes or, as mentioned by @ghybs, not loading the [Leaflet stylesheet](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556436/react-after-render-code), especially the second answer, which addresses this problem:

> One drawback of using componentDidUpdate, or componentDidMount is that they are actually executed before the dom elements are done being drawn, but after they've been passed from React to the browser's DOM.

### Solution

In order to get around this you must wrap your map creation code in a `setTimeout` like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.map = new L.map(element, {
          center: new L.LatLng(41.019829, 28.989864),
          zoom: 14,
          maxZoom: 18,
          layers: new L.TileLayer('...')
      }, 100)
    })
  }
```

I put together a [pen](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/YqYmXQ) which illustrates a working example of a leaflet map inside a React component. Also make sure you are including leaflet's stylesheet:

```
...
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/atlas.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css">
</head>
...
```

I would also recommend using `ref` which I updated the [pen](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/YqYmXQ) to use. You can read more refs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

### Related Questions

[Good way to combine React and Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755251/good-way-to-combine-react-and-leaflet)

[React after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556436/react-after-render-code)

Comment: What you are saying definitely makes sense. And your pen obviously works. But when I try doing the same in my code it breaks. I just copied code from your pen to my (stripped down) files and got shuffled tiles as before. I must be missing something basic here.

Comment: I also tried the trick with `window.requestAnimationFrame(callback)` mentioned in the link you pointed to. No luck.

Comment: @341008 You're most likely missing the stylesheet then.. If you look at the codepen style settings I'm loading it there (not directly through the html section)